Under what conditions on A in $Ax=b$ I could make the entries of the least-square solution as small as I please by controlling b?
Consider the linear system of equations in $x$
\begin{align}
Ax=b,
\end{align}
where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ with $n\ge m$ and $A$ is full column rank. The least-square solution will then be
\begin{align}
x^*=(A^T A)^{-1}A^T b,
\end{align}
where the inverse exists by virtue of the full column rank property on A. Say I could make The entries of the vector $b \in \mathbb R^n$ as small as I please. Under what conditions on $A$ it would follow that the entries of $x^* \in \mathbb R^m$ could also be made as small as we please. Thanks in advance.

I don't think you need any conditions. The concept of 'small entries' is not very rigorous, so I will assume for simplicity that you mean small value of $\| x^* \|_2$. Then
$$ \| x^* \|_2 \leq \| (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top\|_F \|b \|_2,$$
which follows from Consistency of matrix norm — $\| A x \|_2 \leq \| A \|_{F} \| x \|_2$. Now, since $\| (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top\|_F$ is fixed, picking a $b$ with small $\| b\|_2$ will ensure that also $\| x^* \|_2$ is small.

I want to ensure that the entries in absolute value are small enough and obviously that could be ensured by forcing the two norm to be small enough. But I assume that the same inequality holds if we put the entry-wise absolute value. @Matteo

@Fathi: I'm not sure if the same inequality holds if you change the norm. However, if $| x^|_2$ is 'small', then this implies that also the entries of $x^$ are 'small', which should answer your question.

That's correct, however, I would want to establish an argument on the entries themselves instead of the L2 norm. Also, it holds that $\lvert Ax \rvert \leq \lvert A \rvert \lvert x\rvert $, where the absolute value here is entry-wise.

$| x |_2^2 \leq L \Rightarrow |x_i | \leq \sqrt{L}$ for all $i$.
